# How to find the plural version of a stem word in Swift

Tags: swift, string, nlp

I have this code to lemmatize a word to find it's stem version.

```
let text = "people"
let tagger = NLTagger(tagSchemes: [.lemma])
tagger.string = text
tagger.setLanguage(.english, range: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex)
let (tag, range) = tagger.tag(at: text.startIndex, unit: .word, scheme: .lemma)
let stemForm = tag?.rawValue ?? String(text[range]) // person
```

Is it possible to do the reverse in Swift and find the plural version of a word?

Comment: It is important to note that many languages don't just have "singular" and "plural". They could also have dual, paucal, quadral, and more. See also [Grammatical Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number) on Wikipedia. So this is a much more complicated problem than going the other way, and probably needs a different API.

Comment: Actually, I don't see why you would ever need to do this... Presumably, the stem form comes from the user, otherwise you could just hardcode everything in a .stringsdict file. If that's the case, why not also ask the user for the plural form? But note that whatever you are doing, this'd probably only work in languages that have singular and plural forms.